# Codeigniter: Form Validation still fails when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I was wondering why my checkbox fails even after it has already been ticked. It is a checkbox for terms and conditions

Controller:

```
// Load the registration page
public function registration_page(){
    $this->load->view('includes/main_index');
    $this->load->view('recycler/forms/register');
    $this->load->view('includes/footer');
}

public function accept_terms_conditions()
    {
 //    Checkbox name is 'agree' which checks if the value of $checked
 //    is equal to 1 
        $checked = $this->input->post('agree');
        return (int) $checked == 1 ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }

$this->form_validation->set_rules('agree', '', 'callback_accept_terms_conditions');
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
   // After form submission, it always goes here
   $this->registration_page();
} 
else{ /* Proceed to data insertion */ }
```

I printed out the post value of it using print_r function and it returned 1, yet the validation still fails. $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE means that if the form validation has errors, it will go back to the register view, which is the $this->register() method call.

[print_r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6ix8.png)

[ticked checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whnfp.png)

Does anyone know why it keeps failing?

EDIT:
Added the method for loading the registration view which is the register() method

Comment: use `if($this->form_validation->run()){}else{}`

Comment: already tried that, still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
public function accept_terms_conditions() {
  $checked = ($this->input->post('agree')) ? TRUE : FALSE;
  return $checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A checkbox brings "on" as value when it is checked not 1.

```
public function accept_terms_conditions()
{
// returns true if the checkbox 'agree' has been checked 
 return ($this->input->post('agree') === 'on');
}
```

And your condition is wrong, you are saying that if the validation has failed then call method register I think it should be the other way round.

Comment: please explain your code also.

Comment: The condition is not wrong, what it implies is when the form has errors, it will go back to the registration view and show the errors

Comment: Use what Kumar commented

Comment: Also var_dump($this->input->post('agree')) and see if it gives you 1 instead of "on"

Comment: did var_dump and it returns a string, which in my method I converted into integer and it still does not accept it, Kumar's answer is the same, you just tried to validate it the other way around. It didn't change anything at all

Comment: You are saying that if the validation fails then register which is wrong, you should register when the validation passes. When it fails you can get the errors and display them in form.

Comment: no, the register IS JUST A METHOD, it just loads the view :D, check my edit

$this->register() = it is my registration page loader, I have a different view for accepting validated inputs, you must've been confused by my naming convention

Comment: FYI, you can change the value of the checkbox so I would not rely on its text value that much